# При создании объекта, он становится частью уже имеющегося

Tags: blender

При создании нового объекта, он сразу становится частью основного объекта. Blender изучаю недавно, **как создать новый объект, не связанный с уже имеющимся**?

`(Cntrl + J)` - не помогает.

`(Shift + A)` - не помогает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если создавать примитив в режиме "редактирования", то он будет являться частью меша и при переходе в "объектный" режим останется в нём. Если хочешь выделить такой объект в режиме "редактирования", то наведи на него и нажми `L`, а если хочешь ещё и перевести его в отдельный меш, то `P` и выбери `Selection`.

Чтобы создать новый меш, просто выйди из режима "редактирования" `TAB`, нажми `SHIFT+A` и выбери нужный примитив.